# Finding non-zero elements with $x^*x\leq\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

For a given unital Banach *-algebra $A$, let us put $A_+=\{\sum_1^n x^*_ix_i : x_i\in A, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. We  write $x\geq0$ if $x\in A_+$.

What types of (non semi-simple) unital Banach *-algebras contain  some non-zero elements $x$ such that
$$ (\forall n\in \mathbb{N})~~~ nx^*x\leq1$$

Comment: There are many Banach *-algebras with infinitesimal elements. Perhaps, the simplest is the 3-dimensional unital commutative algebra ${\bf C}[X]/\langle X^3\rangle$, where $X^*=X$. The hermitian element $X^2$ is infinitesimal as $0 \le (\alpha-(2\alpha)^{-1}X^2)^2 = \alpha^2-X^2$ for every $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Sorry, I see, now we have the edit, I understand the correct order of the quantifiers.  (This was my failure to read, btw...)

Comment: @ Narutaka OZAWA  It is an amusing example. Thanks a lot for your nice answer.